# How can I programmatically detach an OS disk from its corresponding VM in Azure ARM?

Tags: azure-resource-manager

How can I programmatically detach an OS disk from its VM in Azure ARM ?

Which URL I need to use in order to do that ?

Answer (score 4):

You can not detach an OS disk while the VM is still available. You have to delete the VM, and then you will be able to use the OS disk for another VM.